# How to solve the problem with dynamically changed elements in Table View Cell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I need some advice. I'm trying to create the app where user is able to create some to do at a specific hour. If there are some tasks at the same hour then they should be at one table view cell dedicated to this hour. **Like in example below at 8:00 am**. 
I am not using storyboard. I know how to do this with one element, but the problem is that I am not so sure how to use dynamically change the view according to user's input. My guess is that I should use **Custom Table View** but then I should dynamically register every cell separately (and I am not so sure how to do that). Is there any other method to solve this problem?

UI is similar to this one bellow. [image]

I appreciate every help and advice. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample app which resolves your query.

Key Points:

- Design a custom cell in sample it is : `GrwoingTableViewCell`
- Cell uses `UIStackView` to hold your tasks. UIStackView will take care of UI Update when you add another task in it.
- Make sure you don't give fixed height to either cell or stackView.

Refer this link for sample code https://github.com/Dexter7677/DynamicCell.git